# Angular - Having a link inside the textarea

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a requirement of having a **clickable link** inside a textarea element. Am setting the value for textarea using ng-model of Angular. Please let me know how to achieve this.

Demo for play is below

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.url = "http://stackoverflow.com/"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="myApp" >
    <head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <textarea ng-model = "url"></textarea>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The link should be **editable** + **clickable**?

Comment: @Mistalis Exactly. It should be editable and the edited content also need to be a link which is clickable again

Comment: Its is not possible to have a clickable link inside a textarea. Instaed what you can do is have  a anchor tag whose href you can set to the link and provide a option to edit it using textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, May be it helps you

HTML

```
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <textarea class="textAreaLink" ng-model = "url" ng-click="callFunction()"></textarea>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.textAreaLink{color: blue;cursor: pointer}
.textAreaLink:hover{color: blue;text-decoration: underline;}
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $location) {
   $scope.url = "http://stackoverflow.com/";
   $scope.callFunction = function(){
     $location.path($scope.url);
   }
});
```

Comment: That will trigger the "link" if any part of the textarea is clicked, not just the "link".

Comment: @Quentin Please read the reqauirement before you downvote. The requirement is user can edit text in textarea and click on that as a url.

Comment: @ManojLodhi — It says "a clickable link **inside** a textarea element". It doesn't say "as a textarea element". It doesn't say "filling a textarea element".

Comment: Ok @Quentin waiting for your better answer for this.

Comment: @ManojLodhi — There is no requirement that someone provides a good answer just because they can recognise a bad one.